# Pydantic add information to json schema if the field is optional or not

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

im building my html forms from pydanitc model schema.

```
return orjson.loads(schemas.Person().schema_json())
```

This returns json that looks like this

```
{
    "title": Person,
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "age": {
            "title": "age",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
            "title": "name",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Thats all and great but I need to mark some fields as required in my HTML so i would like schema to look like this

```
{
    "title": Person,
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "age": {
            "title": "age",
            "type": "integer",
            "mandatory": "optional"
        },
        "name": {
            "title": "name",
            "type": "string",
            "mandatory": "required"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my simple pydantic class with my attempt but this is more for actual values not schemas

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: Optional[int]

    #my attempt at this
    def custom_json(self):
        json_data = {}
        for field_name, field_info in self.__annotations__.items():
            field_dict = {
                "title": field_name,
                "type": field_info.__name__,
                "mandatory": "optional" if field_name in self.__annotations__ else "required",
            }
            json_data[field_name] = field_dict
        return orjson.dumps(json_data, option=orjson.OPT_SERIALIZE_NUMPY)
```

So if the field is optional, the mandatory = optional but if the field has nothing the mandatory = required

Comment: So you only want `age` to appear as mandatory in your JSON schema, but in reality, it's optional? So if `age` is not passed, you want your code to ignore it?

Comment: And you want to use `mandatory` to signal whether it's required or not rather than the JSON schema standard using the `required` attribute?

Comment: I've added context at the end. For your second comment, I'm not attached to mandatory key name, if you are talking about returning the 400 with info about what field should be filled in, I have some ui/ux constrains on my hands so passing any key with info will be helpful. If those are not the cases any help will be good